# Ionic bottom fixed content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to implement a simple list page and i am showing one fixed button at bottom of screen which should never scrolling along with list but using my code button scrolling along with list how can i resolve this problem can some one help me please

### html:

```
<ion-content padding>

    <div *ngIf="!events || events.length === 0">
        <p>No messages</p>
    </div>

  <div *ngIf="events && events?.length > 0">
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of events | groupByCategory: 'date'">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">
        {{ group.key }}
      </ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let event of group.list">{{ event.title }}</ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomright" (click)="add()">Add</div>
</ion-content>
```

### css:

```
.bottomright {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: crimson;

    }
```

Comment: Change position value from absolute to fixed. This might work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ion-footer` for that

```
<ion-content></ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: nice..works fine for me. best solution. if you fixed in botton just add: position: fixed, bottom: 0;

Comment: With `position: sticky;`, it doesn't block any content behind it. Everything moves nicely above your footer.

Answer (score 0):

In html code,

```
<button ion-button class="custom-button" (click)="add()">Add</button>
```

In scss code,

```
.custom-button{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```